# Why using import makes Jest ignore mock?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I'm being able to mock a hook called useDI function by mocking the whole module in which it lies, in this way:

```
jest.mock("../../custom/useDI", () => ({
        useDI: jest.fn().mockImplementation((commandType: string) => {
            switch(commandType){
                case requestElementsType: 
                    return () => [
                        {id: 1, elId: 12, sectionId: "1020", regionId: "72"}
                    ] as Element[]
                default: 
                    return []
            }

      }),
}));
```

If in my test I use the mocked function like this (passing a concrete string value), there's no problem.

```
const callElements = useDI(
  "requestElementsType"
) as () => Element[]
```

But if I use a named imported constant (a plain string), then the mock stops working and runs the code as is leading to error of course.

```
const callElements = useDI(
  requestElementsType
) as () => Element[]
```

The project setting uses webpack + ts-loader.

The jest config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts",
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "<rootDir>/test-shim.js",
    "<rootDir>/test-setup.js"
    ],
testEnvironment: "jsdom",
moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less)$": "jest-transform-css"
},
"transform": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/ClientApp/__mocks__/fileTransformer.js"
    }
};
```

Why is this happening?.

Answer (score 1):

After insisting with the code I found the source of the problem: Jest doesn't like relative imports. The code is using an index.ts file that imports modules/files just so all these modules have a single exporting file, in this way:

```
import * from "path/path/functionXFile"
import * from "otherpath/functionYFile"
```

So, when using const requestElementsType it didn't work, because within the file of requestElementsType there were some relative imports. So, it doesn't matter that one avoids relative imports within the mock itself or within the test file, if within the same file of the const you are importing there is some relative import, it's likely there will be problems resolving the import, and that might cancel the mocking procedure (as a fallback mechanism I believe).